# Issues Styling :host in Angular 2

Tags: angular, styling

[Edited to better describe the problem]

I'm having difficulty applying various styles to :host in Angular 2. The simple plunker below demonstrates the problem.  At first I thought that certain styles such as margin/padding weren't getting applied, but it seems that the issue is that the host element  isn't behaving like a normal element. Notice that I've added a border and padding. The border looks really odd and the padding doesn't move the content inside the element at all (although it does appear to affect the way the border looks. This is the style I'm applying:

```
:host {padding:10px; border:1px solid red;}
```

The rendered code looks like this:

```
<sample-component _nghost-cxm-2="">
  <div _ngcontent-cxm-2="">
    <h3 _ngcontent-cxm-2="">Sample Component</h3>
  </div>
</sample-component>
```

I can see in dev tools that the styles are being applied to the `<sample-component>` element, but this is what the page looks like rendered:

[image: Weird border behavior]

I would expect the border to wrap the content inside the component but it is behaving oddly. Here is a sample plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/k7LJcmVlhJINmakBJAau?p=preview

What am I missing?

Comment: its working as expected. I don't think so any problem. https://plnkr.co/edit/Fs2Igm0N2eMTE1dyMsdF?p=preview change value(px) and it will react accordingly.

Comment: Strange even your plnkr isn't working for me.  What browser are  you using?  I've tried Firefox 49.0.1 and chrome 53.0.2785.143. Changing the 100px to any other value doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think you are looking for `margin property`. Padding is just working fine in chrome(latest version). try to add `border:1px solid` then change padding value and you'll see according behavior.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just realized what the problem is.  Host elements are set to `display:inline`. Changing the element to `display:block` fixes the problem.  Not sure how I missed this before.

Comment: I know the rules say not  to do +1 comments, but they say nothing about +5
:heart:

Answer (score 2):

I already showed you that your plunker is working. Other than that you can use `host` metaproperty to apply style to host element as shown below,

**https://plnkr.co/edit/7JquAioc6lUx9bUrPCiZ?p=preview**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sample-component',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>Sample Component</h3>
    </div>
  `,
  host:{
        'style': 'color:red;padding:50px',
       }
})
export class SampleComponent {}
```

**UPDATE after your edit:**
I may not give you an exact answer but there is some problem with `<sample-component>` element/tag which gets created in DOM. Maybe I understand what  you're trying to achieve. I have a workaround for the same.

look at here - **https://plnkr.co/edit/yLLsZABJWCrvE0CWHgFy?p=preview**